# React state variable output as string but passes undefined as a prop

Tags: reactjs

I cannot understand why I am able to render the value of a state variable without an issue but when I pass it as a prop to a child component the value becomes undefined.

truncated source code below:

this.state.pdf renders the url correctly using the code snippet below.

```
render() {
  return (
   ....
   <div>
   <label>PDF:</label>
   <textarea rows="4" cols="100" name="pdf" value={this.state.pdf} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="PDF URL" />
</div>
   ....
```

...later on in the render function I pass the same state variable to another component to render the actual PDF.

```
<div>
  <MammaPDF pdf={this.state.pdf} />
</div>
```

MammaPDF class snippet:

```
class MammaPDF extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
   numPages: null,
   pageNumber: 1,
   pdf: null,
 } 
}

componentDidMount(){
    pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
    console.log("MammaPDF PROPS: ",this.props);  <--- pdf is undefined
    const pdf = this.props.pdf; <---pdf is undefined
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a case, `this.state.pdf` was not resolved when it was passed to `MammaPdf` component. So you should wait for it to be resolved and then call the component.

Can you try below code:-

```
<div>
  {this.state.pdf && <MammaPDF pdf={this.state.pdf} />}
</div>
```

Comment: @Zach this is also a common pattern for components that rely on asynchronous actions like fetching from a backend. it will prevent rendering MammaPDF if this.state.pdf does not exist right away.

Comment: That solved it! Thanks Tarzen and Matt! Will accept answer once it lets me.